# How to reference open source SPM dependencies when authoring an XCFramework?

Tags: dependency-management, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I'm authoring an XCFramework to provide to customers. When I generate the XCFramework bundle, I upload it to a web server, and then reference that URL inside a Swift package using a `.binaryTarget`, which is inside a public repository which I then make available to customers. They are expected to add that repository as a package dependency in their Xcode projects. So far, so good.

In my framework, I want to utilise a third-party open-source Swift package, so I've added it as a package dependency in my private Xcode project which contains my framework. When I compile it locally it all works great.

When it comes to generating the XCFramework, I notice that it compiles, but it doesn't include the third-party dependency (I didn't really expect it to)—instead if a customer were to use it, they'd see a message stating that it couldn't find the third-party module I'm using.

**Which brings me to my question:** how can I best include that third-party library as a dependency of my framework?

I can think of three possible methods:

1. In my framework's public repository (which doesn't contain much more than the Package.swift referencing the XCFramework bundle), add the third-party framework as a dependency. There are a couple potential issues however:

   - `.binaryTarget` doesn't actually allow me to specify any dependencies.
   - I doubt that doing it this way is safe—I don't think there's any guarantee that the version of the third-party SDK compiled by the customer would actually be binary compatible with my framework.
2. Maintain a binary version of the third-party library, and include that as a separate `.binaryTarget` in the public Package.swift file. I think this should work and be safe (because my library would be compiled linking to the same binary), but is a bit more effort and might be problematic if a customer wants to use the same third-party framework in their app (I could see it getting messy).
3. Copy the source files from the dependency into my framework's Xcode project (and probably remove its `public` interfaces), so that the library is included as part of my framework's binary. It's not a neat solution, but I'd imagine it would work, eliminating the dependency problem altogether, and be completely transparent to the customers. It's a bit wasteful if a customer ends up using the same dependency in their own app, as then it'll be included in their app twice (but at least they'll be free to pick their own version).

I'm leaning towards option 2. Are my assumptions about the three methods above correct? Is there a better method?